# index(split(ImportXML formula works in a spreadsheet of mine, not in another?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

`=index(split(ImportXML("http://finance.google.com/finance?q=" & V9, "//td[@data-snapfield='latest_dividend-dividend_yield']/following-sibling::*"), "/"),1,2) / 100`

This formula works in a spreadsheet of mine, but not in another one of mine ... 
V9 is the cell with the name of the stock, e.g. AMZA
In my spreadsheet it returns 19.76%, but in the other Parse error..
I already tried to change the , after V9 in an ;, didn't work

I'm from Europe, Belgium.

Answer (score 0):

Please try (for the version that does not work):

```
=substitute(index(split(ImportXML("http://finance.google.com/finance?q=" & V9; "//td[@data-snapfield='latest_dividend-dividend_yield']/following-sibling::*"); "/");1;2);".";",") / 100
```